# Linking to files in custom 404 page not working in other directories

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

SO I have this 404 page
and I think I understand the problem.
SO this works correctly: sia.github.io/404.html  and so does this:

sia.github.io/ooofdfsdfaablahblah

BUT sia.github.io/1/2/3/

does work, but all the files are missing, as in the jpg and all the .js scripts.

How do I link them so they work?
Like in a script you'd make this problem go away if you had an issue with

/Documents/fileIwant.txt

to

~/Documents/fileIwant.txt

so it would always go home first then get the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you 404 file code

```
<script src="js/Three.js"></script>
<script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>
```

When we access `http://sia.github.io/ooofdfsdfaablahblah` , The js/Three.js will location to `http://sia.github.io/js/Three.js` .

Howere if we access `http://sia.github.io/1/2/3/` , The js/Three.js will location to `http://sia.github.io/1/2/3/js/Three.js` . this file not found.

solution one:

```
<script src="/js/Three.js"></script>
```

or solution two:

```
<base href="http://sia.github.io/" />

<script src="js/Three.js"></script>
```

Comment: solution 1 is not working http://i.imgur.com/BLn6OXg.png  can elaborate on solution 2 a bit more? thank you.

Comment: from your picture, you have a http server configuration problem. Are you using apache or nginx?  Can you give your http server configure ?

Comment: nevermind, solution 1 works! Thank you, was testing with local host and it was showing the error no even with solution 1, obvious why it was, now. lol thank you! :D  solved!